# readFileSync not finding file even though file exists in the current directory

Tags: javascript, typescript, sveltekit, bun

I was working on a Joke API for my SvelteKit project with Bun as the runtime and TypeScript as the programming language. My Joke API involves getting one random line from a text file containing 363 dad jokes. For that I obviously had to read the file. So I implemented that method and it worked splendidly...except for one part. The file reader couldn't find the file. The file location I put in was `./jokes.txt`, which was exactly where it was. However, the file reader said that it just can't find it. I thought that because I was using `Bun.file` to read the file that it was causing issues because Bun is relatively new, so I tried `readFileSync` and that didn't work either.

Here's my code:

```
import { readFileSync } from "fs";

import { db } from "$lib/db";
import { sql } from "drizzle-orm";
import { sqliteTable, integer, text } from 'drizzle-orm/sqlite-core';

export async function GET() {
  let file = readFileSync("./jokes.txt", "utf-8");

  const jokes = file.split("\n");

  const today = new Date();

  const jokecords = sqliteTable("jokecords", {
    id: integer("id").primaryKey(),
    joke: text("joke"),
    month: text("month"),
    day: text("day")
  });

  const matches = await db.select().from(jokecords).where(
    sql`month = ${today.getMonth().toString()} and day = ${today.getDay().toString()}`
  );

  let joke;

  if (matches.length > 0) {
    joke = matches[0];
  }
  else {
    joke = jokes[Math.floor(Math.random() * jokes.length)];
    await db.insert(jokecords).values({
      joke: joke,
      month: today.getMonth().toString(),
      day: today.getDay().toString()
    });
  }

  return {
    joke: joke
  }
}
```

and this is my file structure

```
.sveltekit
node_modules
src
  lib
    db.ts
  routes
    api
      +server.ts
      jokes.txt
      jokes-backup.txt
    +layout.svelte
    +page.svelte
  app.d.ts
  app.html
  app.pcss
static
.gitignore
.npmrc
bun.lockb
package.json
postcss.config.cjs
README.md
svelte.config.js
tailwind.config.cjs
tsconfig.json
vite.config.ts
```

Comment: Would you kindly share your folder structure, including the location of the file that you're trying to read? Otherwise, try to do the reverse: `writeFileSync('./temp.txt', 'text')`. The `temp.txt` file will appear where `readFileSync` expects to find `jokes.txt`, which will help you debug.

Comment: why have you mentioned `svelte`? unless you are writing an SSR app, the frontend is irrelevant

Comment: mind make a backup of your `jokes.txt` before you tell your code to arbitrarily overwrite it :)

Comment: @Octavian i updated my question to have the folder structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readFileSync` can runs in an unespecified way because it depends on the relative path of the execution of code, not your current file. The best way to avoid this is to always compare the location of the code file with the execution runtime and resolve it, like:

```
const path = require("path");

fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./jokes.txt"), "utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

If `readFileSync` throws an `ENOENT` there is point in insisting the file exists. It just doesn't. And most of the time the error happens because the path you are using does not point to the location you think it does.

The relative path `./jokes.txt` *does not* point to the directory where the calling file is located but to the *current working directory* of the process. And that is -- most certainly -- not deep in your filestructure. Try logging a `process.cwd()` to see what the current working directory is.

You could also use `path.resolve('./jokes.txt')` to see, where that relative path actually resolves to. And most certainly you won't find a `jokes.txt` there.

If you are really sure, you want to read a file in the same directory as your current file use  [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#__dirname)

```
readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "jokes.txt"), "utf-8");
```

And just some remarks unrelated to the issue

- Using `readFileSync` in an `async` context kind of defeats the purpose of `async` because it blocks execution. There is an async [fs promises API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api)
- I don't know what `db` is, but

  ```
  const matches = await db.select().from(jokecords).where(
    sql`month = ${today.getMonth().toString()} and day = ${today.getDay().toString()}`
  );
  ```

  uses string templates to create a query, that's considered bad style because it may open your code to SQL injections. Use parameterized queries instead.